# How can i write my own custom form widget in django

Tags: jquery, python, django, forms, file-upload

I have the file field in django form.
Now i want that during rendering my that file field gets replaced by the jquery fileupload plugin.

How can i achieve that

http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a custom form widget for it.  What you do need is to display your form in your django template such that it has the following set up - https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload/blob/master/fileupload/templates/fileupload/picture_form.html

These js files are included:-

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/tmpl.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/load-image.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.fileupload-fp.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/locale.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/main.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/csrf.js"></script>
```

And your form html has these elements with the form's id being `fileupload`:-

```
    <form id="fileupload" method="post" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
            <div class="span7">
                <span class="btn btn-primary fileinput-button">
                    <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Add files...</span>
                    <input type="file" name="file" multiple>
                </span>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success start">
                    <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Start upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Cancel upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                    <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Delete files</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            </div>
            <div class="span5 fileupload-progress fade">
                <div class="progress progress-success progres-striped active">
                    <div class="bar" style="width:0%"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fileupload-loading"></div>
        <table class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery"></tbody></table>
    </form>
    <div class="fileupload-content">
        <table class="files"></table>
        <div class="fileupload-progressbar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```